# The difference between the meanings of "assumption" and "hypothesis" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

What is the difference between the meanings of "assumption" and "hypothesis" in the following context.

> Feminist researchers have also developed alternatives to assumptions,
>   research questions, and hypotheses that they criticize. [[Source]](https://books.google.fr/books?id=8B0xDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=Feminist%20researchers%20have%20also%20developed%20alternatives%20to%20assumptions,%20research%20questions,%20and%20hypotheses%20that%20they%20criticize.&source=bl&ots=yQr5w9in70&sig=n_KbCjlXQ-5lK-B27Ilns66cs8g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDp5PN4-HXAhVNaVAKHcYgAUIQ6AEIKzAA)

The definitions that the main dictionaries on the web [for example compare [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assumption) and [here]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hypothesis)  offer are all to the effect that both words mean something taken for granted without it being proved and basing other views on it.

Is there a technical difference between the meanings of these two terms?

Answer (score 1):

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hypothesis) lists among its senses

> **hypothesis**: a supposition or proposed explanation made on the basis of limited evidence as a starting point for further
>   investigation

and [AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/assumption)

> **assumption** 4. Something taken for granted or accepted as true without proof; a supposition

The difference here is that a *hypothesis* involves taking the reasoned approach 'Let's assume for the time being that W is true' and going on to show that X and not-Y say follow, and Z is very likely, if the assumption was correct. An *assumption* need not be so grounded in the scientific method, and indeed may be little more than a prejudice, not intended to be checked out but used as if incontrovertibly true.